# How to remove last character of a sentence only when it is 'a' in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sentence 'Welcome to a project are you a', Here I need to remove 'a' that should only remove when sentence contains last letter as 'a',else I have tried this code below its working here,but its not working in my project.

### html

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messages"></ul>
```

### script

```
 var text = 'Welcome to project, are you a (1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident)';
    var regex = /\((.*)\)/;
    var m;

    m = regex.exec(text);
        console.log(m[1]);
        // 1. new user one, 2. test user two, 3. minor Accident one or 4. Major Accident
        var list = m[1];

        var items = list.split(/([\d]. )/g);

        var message = $('.messages');

    var introText = text.split('(');
    var test = introText[0]
    alert(test.replace(/\a$/, ""));
```

Comment: So what is different here vs your project? Really impossible for us to answer when what we are given works....

Comment: `\ba`, not `\a` is probably what you're after

Comment: @Madbreaks or just /a$/?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yeah, I was assuming op would only want to match `a` as a letter and not as e.g. part of another word

Comment: I have edited code as per my project

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex easily:

```js
var s = "Welcome to project are you a";
let t = s.replace(/\a$/,"")
console.log(t)                         // --> Welcome to project are you
```

```js
var s = "Welcome to project are you x";
let t = s.replace(/\a$/,"")
console.log(t)                         // --> Welcome to project are you x
```

Note that `.$` will match any character at the end of a string and so `a$` will mach the character 'a' at the end of the string.

Comment: The 'a' will not be removed if there is a space after the 'a'

Comment: ... **only** `remove when sentence contains` **last letter**
`as 'a'.` ^

Comment: Yes, When the `last letter is an a`. Space is not a letter.

Comment: @thatguy so you're saying 'a' should be removed in the string `ba@##\ %^&^ /&**()_+` ?

Comment: I'm probably taking the question to literal, but since the code provided already works, I assume that if there is a space, number, or special character at the end of the sentence it should still remove the 'a'  from the sentence if it is the last *letter*. But probably just being too literal.

Comment: I have edited code as per my project  its not working